# How to count recurring characters at the beginning of a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring, qregularexpression

Im dealing with a list of lines, and I need to count the hashes that occur at the beginning.

```
#  item 1
## item 1, 1
## item 1, 2
#  item 2
```

and so on.

If each line is a QString, how can I return the number of hashes occurring at the beginning of the string?

```
QString s("### foo # bar ");
int numberOfHashes = s.count("#"); // Answer should be 3, not 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trivially:

```
int number_of_hashes(const QString &s) {
    int i, l = s.size();
    for(i = 0; i < l && s[i] == '#'; ++i);
    return i;
}
```

In other languages (mostly interpreted ones) you have to fear iteration over characters as it's slow, and delegate everything to library functions (generally written in C). In C++ iteration is perfectly fine performance-wise, so a down-to-earth `for` loop will do.

---

Just for fun, I made [a small benchmark](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/prefixcount_benchmark/) comparing this trivial method with the `QRegularExpression` one from OP, possibly with the RE object cached.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <vector>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QRegularExpression>

int number_of_hashes(const QString &s) {
    int i, l = s.size();
    for(i = 0; i < l && s[i] == '#'; ++i);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    const int count = 100000;
    std::vector<QString> ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) ss.push_back(QString(rand() % 10, '#') + " foo ## bar ###");
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    unsigned tot = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        for(const QString &s: ss) tot += number_of_hashes(s);
    }
    std::cerr<<"plain loop: "<<t.elapsed()*1000./count<<" ns\n";
    t.restart();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        for(const QString &s: ss) tot += QRegularExpression("^[#]*").match(s).capturedLength();
    }
    std::cerr<<"QRegularExpression, rebuilt every time: "<<t.elapsed()*1000./count<<" ns\n";

    QRegularExpression re("^[#]*");
    t.restart();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        for(const QString &s: ss) tot += re.match(s).capturedLength();
    }
    std::cerr<<"QRegularExpression, cached: "<<t.elapsed()*1000./count<<" ns\n";
    return tot;    
}
```

As expected, the `QRegularExpression`-based one is *two orders of magnitude* slower:

```
plain loop: 0.7 ns
QRegularExpression, rebuilt every time: 75.66 ns
QRegularExpression, cached: 24.5 ns
```

Comment: Could you please add my idea to the benchmark as well. You know, out of pure curiosity and just for fun.

Answer (score 4):

Here I use the standard algorithm [`find_if_not`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to get an iterator to the first character that is not a hash. I then return the distance from the start of the string to that iterator.

```
int number_of_hashes(QString const& s)
{
    auto it = std::find_if_not(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [](QChar c){return c == '#';});
    return std::distance(std::begin(s), it);
}
```

**EDIT**: the `find_if_not` function only takes a unary predicate, not a value, so you have to pass a lambda predicate.

Answer (score 3):

```
int numberOfHashes = 0;
int size = s.size();
QChar ch('#');
for(int i = 0; (i < size) && (s[i] == ch); ++i) {
    ++numberOfHashes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution without a *for-loop*:

```
QString s("### foo # bar ");
int numberOfHashes = QRegularExpression("^[#]*").match(s).capturedLength();
```

Comment: Invoking the wrath of regular expressions for such a simple problem is probably overkill.

Comment: Compared to a plain ad-hoc loop this is probably several orders of magnitude slower. Whether this is important in your use case, only you know, although, given that the "manual" solution is of similar length/effort to write and is orders of magnitude faster I wouldn't even consider an alternative; sloppy abuse of the processing power we have today is probably why most software is always slow, even though hardware gets faster. Still, if you are doing it on many lines at least cache the `QRegularExpression` object!

Comment: @Akiva: I added a small benchmark to my answer; as expected, your solution is ~100 times slower.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
int beginsWithCount(const QString &s, const QChar c) {
  int n = 0;
  for (auto ch : s)
    if (c == ch) n++; else break;
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Qt approach, making use of [`QString::indexOf(..)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#indexOf):

```
QString s("### foo # bar ");
int numHashes = 0;

while ((numHashes = s.indexOf("#", numHashes)) == numHashes) {
    ++numHashes;
} // numHashes == 3
```

> ```
> int QString::indexOf(const QString &str, int from = 0, 
>                      Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive) const
> ```
>
> Returns the index position of the first occurrence of the string `str` in this string, searching forward from index position `from`. Returns `-1` if `str` is not found.

Starting at index `0`, the string `s` is searched for the first occurrence of `#`, and thereafter use a predicate to test whether this occurrence is at index `0`. If not terminated, proceeds with index `1`, and so on.

This will not short-circuit a final possibly full string search, however. In case a hash is not found at its expected position, prior to the final failing predicate check, the string will be searched fully (or until first hash at wrong position) a single time.

Comment: The search is unnecessary: we only care about the beginning characters. The search raises the cost from O(1) to O(N) and is a pessimization.

Comment: @KubaOber as I have already explicitly pointed out in the last paragraph of my answer. I still think a `QString` approach can have a merit in this Q&A, naturally including the last paragraph.